# Non-Standard Webfont EurostileTRegExt

Tags: css, fonts

I would like the font of my website to be `EurostileTRegExt`. But when I type it in the `font-family`, it doesn't appear. I know it's a non-standard font (I had to download it) but is there any way that the server publishes this font? I tried uploading it onto the server but no luck.

I have the .tff-file from [here](http://www.myfontfree.com/eurostiletregext-myfontfreecom126f66541.htm).

```
body
{ 
  font-family: EurostileTRegExt, Arial, Georgia, Cordia New, Arial, Helvetica;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify where the font is, and give it its name.

```
@font-face 
{
    font-family: EurostileTRegExt;
    src: url(yourpath/EurostileTRegExt.tff);
}
```

Comment: I tried doing that but it doesn't work... I uploaded the .tff to my server but src: url(EurostileTRegExt.tff) doesn't succeed nor does src: url(fonts/EurostileTRegExt.tff). I removed all font related lines in the body and added the @ font-face, nothing works... Is having the .tff enough and uploading it to the server?

Comment: You still need declare the font in the body or the selectors you wish to use that font on. This only specifies the name of the font and where it can fint it on the server.

Comment: Now it works, thanks! I only wrote @font-face {} and left out the "font-family:.." in body {}.

Answer (score 0):

add following to your head tag

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
   @font-face {
    font-family: Pompadur; /* Name of the font, as specified in font file */
    src: url(fonts/pompadur.ttf); /* Path to font file on your server */
   }
   h1 {
    font-family: Pompadur, 'Comic Sans MS', cursive;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
```

Comment: Have a more detailed look here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Comment: I tried doing that but it doesn't work... My <head> is in a seperate php-file, does that have to do anything with it? I uploaded the .tff to my server but src: url(EurostileTRegExt.tff) doesn't succeed nor does src: url(fonts/EurostileTRegExt.tff). I removed all font related lines in the body and added the @ font-face, nothing works... Is having the .tff enough and uploading it to the server?

Comment: Now it works, thanks! I only wrote @font-face {} and left out the "font-family:.." in body {}.